# setTimeout() stuck in a neverending loop

Tags: angular

I want to get the height of divs that I use in a few components, with my HTML looking almost like the following:

```
<div  #dataHeadlines *ngFor="let group of catt" [ngClass]='hf(dataHeadlines)'>
        <h4>{{ group }}</h4>
            <nlr-child-headlines [data]=sortedData [title]=group></nlr-child-headlines> 
    </div>
```

and my function that I call looks like:

```
hf(element) {
        //setTimeout(() => { 
        this.height = element.offsetHeight;
        console.log("juliet function height = " + this.height);
        //},0);
    }
```

This gives me all the values as zero due to the fact that the information is async. But when I remove the comment marks, the setTimeout() function runs, and gives me the values that I want, but it just keep going like my 3 year old...

How do I make it STOP! And if you can help with the setTimeout() problem that would also be nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following actions will trigger automatic change detection.

*Events - User events like click, change, input, submit, …
XMLHttpRequests - E.g. when fetching data from a remote service
Timers - setTimeout(), setInterval(), because JavaScript*

So setTimeout trigger change which in turn calls hf() and the loop continues.

You should bind ngClass to a variable instead of a function call and Angular will handle everything for you.

Comment: `So setTimeout trigger change which in turn calls hf() and the loop continues.` This was the thing that made it stop, so thank you for the answer. I took some time to see how I can change it to work differently. But you did answer the question and I learned form it. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Binding to functions in the template causes the function to be run on every change detection turn (which happens quite frequently).

It is better to assign the result to a property and bind to this property instead.

```ts
hf(element) {
    //setTimeout(() => { 
    this.height = element.offsetHeight;
    console.log("juliet function height = " + this.height);
    this.someCssClass = 'xxx';
    //},0);
}
```

```ts
<div  #dataHeadlines *ngFor="let group of catt" [ngClass]='someCssClass'>
```

I can't tell from the information you provided, what would be a good place to call `hf()` from. Usually it's some kind of event (lifecycle callback, observable event, ...)

Comment: Thanks Gunter, I got it to stop. I will need to make a small plunker to actually show my problem in a new question.